# Inserting extra line breaks using VIM

Tags: vim, text-manipulation

I have an interview transcript with continuous text. At times, the names of the person speaking are written (Aron:, Kalle:, Tomas: etc.). I want to insert a line break before every name that is followed by a colon (:) (names, which I  specify).

How can I script this in VIM so that when I run the command, it goes through the entire text file and insert those extra linebreaks?

In other words, I want to turn this:

```
Aron: bla, bla, bla
Kalle: yes, yes, yes
```

into:

```
Aron: bla, bla, bla

Kalle: yes, yes, yes
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this simple command:

```
:g/^/pu_
```

- `g/^/` will match every line, then exec command below.
- `pu _` will put the text from register `_`(the black hole register) after current matched line.

---

You can also use the `:substitute` command:

```
:%s/$/\r
```

---

Yet another one which uses external `sed`:

```
:%!sed G
```

---

All commands have the same length. Pick one you like.

Comment: Thanks. What if I only want to insert the line break every time the string "Aron:" occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
:%s#^\(\w*:\)#\r\1#g

- % : serach in all lines
- s : search and replace command
- # : separators (I perfer '#' to '/')
- \(\w*:\) : grep your required format (Aron:, Kalle:, Tomas: etc.) and store in \1
- \r : for inserting a line
- g : global search and replace
```

Comment: So is it w* that I replace with Aron:?

Comment: \w* matches with a word say Aron and so '\w*:' should be replaced by Aron:. kev's ans performs insertion on every line, which is not your requirement, I guess. here we grep for required pattern and insert a new line only a line before pattern match.